# RS232: To parity or not to parity?

Tags: serial-port

I'm starting to write code for a device that'll stream data in and out in full duplex mode, so I'll be using hardware handshaking and setting a break condition when something goes wrong. But when it comes to error detection it's less clear what the best way to go is.

RS232 has built-in parity checking that I could use. As I understand it, if I use 8 data bits, one parity bit and one stop bit then the packet on the wire will be 10 bits. This means that for every 1024 bytes I send, I'm also sending 128 bytes of validation information interleaved with it.

Since parity is a 50/50 thing for each byte, it's not too unlikely that a short burst of noise lasting less than one byte will cause corruption that's still consistent with the parity bit. So it doesn't seem a reliable test.

If I use a checksum at the end of each 1024 bytes, which is still only 80ms at 115200 baud, my validation overhead goes down from 12% to less than 1%, even if I use a 64 bit checksum. And it's harder to miss corruption.

Is parity simply a technology that was useful in the days of sub 100 baud connections and is long since obsolete, and I should go with a block checksum, or am I missing something?

Comment: Also something worth to consider: is short burst noise likely to appear in the environment where this is used? If so, RS-232 is definitely _not appropriate_, it is to be regarded as an indoors, office environment bus. A far better alternative is RS-485 (code compatible) or better yet, CAN (not compatible).

Comment: @Lundin [RS-485](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rs4850) will not meet OP need of "data in and out in full duplex mode" and it is not a full duplex communication protocol.  [RS-422](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rs422) would provide the better electrical noise immunity suggested, yet still retain full duplex capability.

Comment: @Lundin - *" RS-232...is to be regarded as a...bus"*  -- Not a "bus" but a communications link.  A bus implies control, addressing and even power as well as data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Suggest calculating and appending a [CRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#Computation_of_CRC) instead of checksum.  16-bit may meet your needs - I'd use 32-bit.  A 16-bit with random noise will fail 1 in 64k.  32-bit 1 in 4G.
2. Checksum, though easy to calculate suffers from noise burst that are interpreted as a 0 - not that uncommon as far as serial errors go.
3. The overhead calculation is a bit off.  1 start + 8 data + 1 stop bit = 10 vs. 10 + parity = 11.
4. Parity is not worth it IMO. Does not detect much beyond what the framing error (wrong stop bit) provides.  Does not provide message integrity.

Comment: CRC and checksum are two different things (both of them sloppily used). CRC is an _algorithm_ (cyclic redundancy check) used to calculate a _checksum_. More formally, a checksum that was obtained from a CRC algorithm and added to a package, is known as a [FCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_check_sequence) (frame check sequence).

Comment: @Lundin In my experience a checksum (value) is a summation (algorithm) of previous data - hence the name "checksum".  A check code (value) is a generic appellation describing a code append to a message of which a cyclic redundancy check (CRC) is but one of many algorithms used to calculate such.  The phrase "CRC" certainly applies to an algorithm.  But it also applies to the check code itself.    Many communication standards call the check code the "CRC"  (e.g. ISO 15693.) but then maybe ISO is not as formal as it should be and should call it an FCS?

Answer (score 5):

Parity is a very crude, old-fashioned way of error detection. And it adds a lot of overhead to your transmission: actually it adds far more latency than a checksum. For 1024 bytes sent at 115200 baud, parity would cause an extra delay of 8.88ms. So it is best to forget you ever heard about parity and consider it as an obsolete feature.

As for which checksum algorithm to use, CRC is widely recognized as the best option. However, a CRC with a 64 bit polynomial will take quite some time to compute.

Consider splitting up the big chunk of data into smaller packages, each with a smaller checksum, such as CRC-8 or CRC-16.

Comment: Had already accepted the other answer by the time this appeared, and both're pretty equivalent, but thanks for it.

Comment: @CraigGraham The site allows you to change your mind :) Though you can upvote all of the answers you find helpful.